# JQuery animate doesn't work on first click

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Animating the height of the content doesn't work on first click of the tabs. After first-click it works. Here is the link ::

http://jsfiddle.net/JU4rp/

HTML

```
    <div id="tabs-container">

    <ul class="tabs-menu">
        <li class="current"><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab">
        <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sit amet purus urna. Proin dictum fringilla enim, sit amet suscipit dolor dictum in. Maecenas porttitor, est et malesuada congue, ligula elit fermentum massa, sit amet porta odio est at velit. Sed nec turpis neque. Fusce at mi felis, sed interdum tortor. Nullam p.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
            <p>Donec semper dictum sem, quis pretium sem malesuada non. Proin venenatis orci vel nisl porta sollicitudin. Pellentesque sit amet massa et orci malesuada facilisis vel vel lectus. Etiam tristique volutpat auctor. Morbi nec massa eget sem ultricies fermentum id ut ligula. Praesent aliquet adipiscing dictum. Suspendisse dignissim dui tortor. Integer faucibus interdum justo, mattis commodo elit tempor id. Quisque ut orci orci, sit amet mattis nulla. Suspendisse quam diam, feugiat at ullamcorper eget, sagittis sed eros. Proin tortor tellus, pulvinar at imperdiet in, egestas sed nisl. Aenean tempor neque ut felis dignissim ac congue felis viverra. </p>

        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>

</div>
```

CSS

```
p{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.tabs-menu {
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    transform:rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-right: -68px;
    margin-left: -68px;
}

.tabs-menu li {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #9CCD6C;
    list-style: None;
}

.tabs-menu li.current {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #9CCD6C;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9CCD6C;
    z-index: 5;
}

.tabs-menu li a {
    padding: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #9CCD6C;
    text-decoration: none; 
}

.tabs-menu .current a {
    color: #fff;
}

.tab {
    border: 1px solid #9CCD6C;
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    width: auto;
}

.tab-content {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
}

#tab-1 {
 display: block;   
}
```

JScript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs-menu a").on('click',function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");        
        $(tab).css("display","block");
        $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(".tab").animate({
            height: $(tab).height()+40,
        }, "slow");

    }
    );

});
```

I am very new to Jquery and I have been using other people's code and manipulating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this instance, the initial height of the `.tab` element was the default value, `auto`. This is why the animation wasn't taking place initially. To solve this, simply set a height on the `.tab` element.

[**Updated example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/Pb4LM/) - it works now.

```
.tab {
    border: 1px solid #9CCD6C;
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    width: auto;
    height:140px;      /* Added this */
}
```

The above solution relies on setting a hardcoded height, therefore it won't work for dynamic content of varying heights. It would be better to set the height of the element to the computed height.

```
$('.tab').height($('.tab').height());
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/HrxK8/1/) demonstrating that it now works for varying heights.

Answer (score 1):

It's not animating at first because the height of tab 2 is not set to match the height of tab 1. To get it to animate, you need to set the height of tab 2 to that of tab 1 when the page is  first loaded

See this fiddle where I have added the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/M6m8R/1/

```
var firstTabHeight = $('#tab-1').height() + 40;
$('.tab').height(firstTabHeight);
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't know the height of the .tab which is inserted as inline css after the click event occurs, so either you should dynamically add as inlne css the initial .tab height with jQuery outside of your click eventHandler or you have to insert 140px to your css as default value and remember to change it if default content there changes (so its height).

I would choose the dynamic option using sth like:

```
$('.tab').css('height', $('.tab').height());
```

because i don't want to remember useless things about my projects ;-) Have fun http://jsfiddle.net/JU4rp/19/.